# Separability properties of an arbitrary mixed 3 qubit state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Suppose I have a 3 qubit density matrix $\rho$. 
How do I tell if it is completely separable,

$\rho=\sum_ip_i\rho^{(1)}_i\otimes\rho^{(2)}_i\otimes\rho^{(3)}_i $

or biseparable across a partition

$\rho=\sum_ip_i\rho^{(1)}_i\otimes\rho^{(2,3)}_i $

or a mixture of biseparable states across different partitions

$\rho=\sum_ip_i\rho^{(a_i)}_i\otimes\rho^{(b_i,c_i)}_i $,

where $(a_i,b_i,c_i)$ is some permutation of (1,2,3), or tripartite entangled (i.e. none of the above).

Is there a standard way to check? Does it generalize to $n$ qubits?